# simple yet complex SQL query needed

Tags: sql-server-2008

### Background

I have a table (well its a derived table) but it looks like this: I do not have read/write permissions but I can copy the entire structure to a temp table.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
id |  R_2010 |  R_2009  |   W_2010 |  W_2009 |  M_2010 |   M_2009 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
1      33%       56%         47%       56%       40%        33%
2      N/D       N/D         N/D       N/D       N/D        N/D
3      64 %      77 %        71 %      84 %      49 %       71 %
4      N/D       N/D         N/D       N/D       89%        84%
5      56%       N/D         58%       N/D       62%        N/D
6      100%      0%          100%      50%       100%       50%
7      94%       71%         94%       82%       100%       82%
```

Basically what I want to do is the following:

```
If %_2010 is between 80 - 100 AND there is an increase from 
 %_2009 to %_2010 by 20 percent, i want this row. 


Similary  If %_2010 is between 70 - 80 AND there is an increase from 
 %_2009 to %_2010 by 25 percent, i want this row. 


Similary  If %_2010 is between < 70 AND there is an increase from 
 %_2009 to %_2010 by 30 percent, i want this row. 


* % = R, W, M
```

### Example

Consider row 8. Its R_2010 > 80 so we want rule one. 
Also R_2010 - R_2009 = 20 percent points so we are interested in this.

Also in row in, W_2010 > 80 so we want rule one
So W_2010 - W_2009 = 41 which is more then 20 percent so I want this row as well. 
Notice is the same row as above.

In Row 8, M_2010 > 80 however the difference is not more then 20 percent 
so I am not interested.

so I want:

```
------------------------------------------
NEW TEMP TABLE 
------------------------------------------
id, type,  increaseBy
------------------------------------------
8,  R,     20
8,  W,     41
```

### Problem

As you can see, all these columns are `VARCHAR`, they are not the same length (ie, 0%, 20%, 100%) and some don't even have a percent (`N/D`). Some have a space between the number and '%'

### Current Work..

Well I am working on it, and i will update this post as I have something that dosn't return an error

Comment: You keep talking about row 8, but in the table you show at the top, I only see 7 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I's suggest the first thing to do is fix your derived table to get rid of any nonnumeric characters. Null out the "N/D" and remove the spaces and % signs. Then you have numbers that you can do something with.

You are also going to have to join to this table at least three times since you seem to want separate records at the end, one for the R records, one for the W records and one for the M records. Perhaps the derived table shouldn't try to put them in one line.

If you want theresults on one line thoug for each type, you can use the case statment to get the results you want.